# How can i order by a case statement thats in a sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi all first time poster learning (MS)SQL :) - I hope you can help. I have the below query but would like to order it with highest paying category coming first.

If i try an order by salaries within the subquery, i'm told thats not allowed.

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 60
>  The ORDER BY clause is
> invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and
> common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also
> specified.If i try it outside of the query it tells me its also not
> allowed as salaries is not in the group by

```
Select test.rating, COUNT(rating) as total
FROM (
  select ID, name, salaries, 
         CASE
             WHEN salaries \> 12345 THEN 'paid well'
             WHEN salaries \< 12345 THEN 'underpaid'
             WHEN salaries = 12345  THEN 'average'
             ELSE 'null'
         END AS rating
  from dupes
) test
GROUP by test.rating
```

From above this is my current output and exactly how I want it, but would like the Paid well category first, followed by average, then underpaid. Can anyone please help me?

```
rating     total

average      2


null                 5

underpaid     4  

paid well   
    1
```

Comment: The ORDER BY should be at the end, i.e. after GROUP BY.

Comment: FYI, it's a `CASE` **expression**; it returns a scalar value. T-SQL doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: The order of rows in a resultset is only guaranteed when the outermost query has an ORDER BY clause. Such a clause is simply not valid within the subquery that forms the derived table named "test" since rows in a table have no order by definition. It is also a little odd that you refer to test.rating twice but you write `COUNT(rating) as total`. Develop good habits - write consistent code, reference every column using the appropriate alias, use statement terminators.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a ORDER BY after the GROUP BY (ie it will be the last action performed):

```
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN test.rating='null' then 99
        WHEN test.rating='Paid Well' then 1
        WHEN test.rating='Average' then 2
        WHEN test.rating='Underpaid' then 3
        ELSE 4
   END
```

Comment: test.rating will never be NULL, but possibly `'null'`.

Comment: Well, just decide where you want to place the rows with value 'null' and assign a number to it that you can order by, as in the example.

Comment: I meant you need to do a string comparison, since OP has the string literal `'null'`.

Comment: This code worked a treat! Thank you Tinazmu & jarh.  I need to practice CASE in ORDER BY clause further. Are there any common instances where this is used?

Comment: The custom sort ordering is almost always done this way

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT test.rating, COUNT(rating) AS total
FROM (
  select ID, name, salaries, 
         CASE
             WHEN salaries \> 12345 THEN 'paid well'
             WHEN salaries \< 12345 THEN 'underpaid'
             WHEN salaries = 12345  THEN 'average'
             ELSE 'null'
         END AS rating
  from dupes
) test
GROUP by test.rating
ORDER BY
   CASE
       WHEN test.rating = 'Paid Well' THEN 1
       WHEN test.rating = 'Average' THEN 2
       WHEN test.rating = 'Underpaid' THEN 3
       WHEN test.rating = 'null' THEN 99
       ELSE 4
   END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH detaildata AS (SELECT test.rating, COUNT(rating) AS total FROM ( select ID, name, salaries, CASE WHEN salaries \> 12345 THEN 'paid well' WHEN salaries \< 12345 THEN 'underpaid' WHEN salaries = 12345  THEN 'average' ELSE 'null' END AS rating from dupes ) test GROUP by test.rating ) SELECT rating, total FROM detaildata ORDER BY rating
```

Comment: Hi Touhidalam69.  This didnt show the average data for some reason? I will look into the WITH clause a bit more as ive not come across that before. Do you use it often when you code?